# Custom datatable module in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been trying to create my own datatable, but facing issues.
So my app structure is like so:
[image]

where hkdt in my custom datatable module, I want to use this in my app module so that it is accessible everywhere.

hkdt.component.ts is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hkdt',
    exportAs: "hkdt",
    templateUrl: './hkdt.html',
    styleUrls: ['./hkdt.css']
})
export class HkdtComponent {
}
```

hkdt.module.ts is:

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import {HkdtComponent} from "./hkdt.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [HkdtComponent],
    exports: [HkdtComponent]
})
export class HkdtModule {
}
```

index.ts is:

```
export * from './hkdt.component';
export * from './hkdt.module';
```

and I want to use it in my app.module.ts like so:

In my imports array of app.module.ts I import HkdtModule from `import {HkdtModule} from "./core/hkdt";`

and using it in some module like so:
`<hkdt></hkdt>`

below is my app.module.ts:

```
import {HkdtModule} from "./core/hkdt";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SignInComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HkdtModule
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but I get a console error:

[image]

Can anybody help me resolve me this problem.

**Note:** I do not want to import the component in the module and use it because I want to later publish my hkdt as a plugin and I want to make it work independently in a pluggable manner.

Comment: Can you please show the app.module file? it should work, as long as the module is correctly imported... Unless you're using the component in another module inside app.module

Comment: @briosheje I have added app.module.ts to the question

Comment: Are you trying use `hkdt` from another component that has it's own `module`?

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal The import procedure seems correct, can you please explain where you are using the component? The only possible case that I can think about is you are using the component inside another module (which resides in app module, maybe).

Comment: @theblindprophet yes I am using hkdt and yes it has its own module

Comment: @briosheje I am importing HkdtModule in app.module and then using `<hkdt></hkdt>` in app.component .